# Radioactivity in pegmatite

Tags: radioactivity

The site in question has pegmatite which includes uranium-bearing microlite. The age of the pegmatite is 1.3 billion years. I've measured the pegamtite at 4.2 mR/hr (see photo)

The chart below show the decay series for U-238. The first number is 4.468 * 10^9 years = 4,468,000,000.

What can be said about the composition of radioactive element(s) and the nature/strength of the radioactivity itself? (Edit: Can I assume it started with U-238? How much U-238 remains? What other of the decayed elements are there? What is the exposure danger to a human?)

Nuclide Half-Life   Radiation *
U-238   4.468*10^9 years    alpha
Th-234  24.1 days   beta
Pa-234m 1.17 minutes    beta
U-234   244,500 years   alpha
Th-230  77,000 years    alpha
Ra-226  1,600 years alpha
Rn-222  3.8235 days alpha
Po-218  3.05 minutes    alpha
Pb-214  26.8 minutes    beta
Bi-214  19.9 minutes    beta
Po-214  63.7 microseconds   alpha
Pb-210  22.26 years beta
Bi-210  5.013 days  beta
Po-210  138.378 days    alpha
Pb-206  stable  -

[image: meter]

Comment: What do you want to know ? Which mass of pegmatite have you measured ? How far away is the counter from the pegmatite ? ? Does it detect alpha, beta and gamma rays ? What is the purity of the pegmatite ?

Comment: The instrument measures this reading from directly against the rock up to a couple of inches away. The measurement is of gamma rays. I'm not sure how to answer your questions about mass and purity. Added to question based on your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What can be said about the composition of radioactive element(s) and the nature/strength of the radioactivity itself?" **Nothing**.

- Uranium from some areas has been depleted by [formation of a natural reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor).
- There are [other radioactive elements](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/5201124) in pegmatite that are *not* daughters of uranium decay, e.g. <sup>232</sup>Th. Furthermore, the ratio of uranium to these other elements varies with with locale.

You'd need further tests, whether chemical or physical (e.g., measuring the types and energies of radiation), to get an idea of the composition of the rock.